# How to use raw_gadget to simulate wifi card in order to test the r8192u_usb.ko driver of linux kernel without real hardware

Tags: linux-device-driver

I want to test drivers/staging/rtl8192u/r8192u_usb.ko of linux kernel without real hardware. I try to use raw_gadget to simulate the Realtek RTL8192 USB WiFi card, but I could not reach the rtl8192_usb_probe() function. Do you know what configuration should I do in order to simulate the Realtek RTL8192 USB WiFi card?

Comment: There is a new tool that targets exactly such a use case, i.e. emulate hardware in order to test Linux kernel drivers. I think what you can do is to conduct a research before asking here. Maybe there are better approaches exists. Also consider to write a QEmu support if none yet written.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.